# Scrollviewer back to the old position after scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

Here's my scrollviewerr to scroll a Grid. I'm testing in my phone and when I scroll the page up or down it back to the first position :( How can I solve this problem ?

```
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" 
              Grid.RowSpan="3" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              Background="#CC000000"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" >

        <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="10,10,346,560" Source="/HoroscopeImages/bachduong.png"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Bạch Dương" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="36" Width="117"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,151,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="(21/3 - 19/4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="36" Width="117"/>
        <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="169,10,187,560" Source="/HoroscopeImages/kimnguu.png"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that the `container` in which ur `scrollViewer` lies has enough `height` or set it `auto`.